# Hide private methods and members in c++

Tags: c++, private

The question is that I have multiple specialized base classes to be used by clients to develop the derived classes at clients' end. The multiple specialized base classes are all derived from the same base class. So the derived classes by clients are derived from the same base class, and the same base class pointer can be used to point all client classes. My question is how can I hide the private members and methods of base and specialized base classes from clients, and still allows the client to develop derived classes from the same base class? The very simplified codes are as follows:

In Base.h. This is the single common base of all the following specialized base classes.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    ~Base() {}

    void Start();

private:
    // methods to override by derived class
    virtual void DoExecute() {}

private:
    void Execute() {
        // Do something here 
        DoExecute();
        // Do something here 
    }

    // Other private methods and members 
}
```

In Base.cpp

```
void Base::Start() {
    Execute(); 
}
```

In SpecializedBase1.h. One specialized base class for clients to derived special client class.

```
class SpecializedBase1 : public Base {
public:
    SpecializedBase1();
    ~SpecializedBase1();

private:
    // methods to override by derived class
    virtual void DoExecute() {}

    // Other private methods and members specialized for this class
}
```

In SpecializedBase2.h. Another specialized base class for clients to derived special client class.

```
class SpecializedBase2 : public Base {
public:
    SpecializedBase2();
    ~SpecializedBase2();

private:
    // methods to override by derived class
    virtual void DoExecute() {}

    // Other private methods and members specialized for this class
}
```

In clients' end, two classes are derived to be called by us.

```
class ClientClass1 : public SpecializedBase1 {
public:
    ClientClass1();
    ~ClientClass1();

private:
    // override base class 
    void DoExecute() {}

    // Other private methods and members specialized for this class
}

class ClientClass2 : public SpecializedBase2 {
public:
    ClientClass2();
    ~ClientClass2();

private:
    // override base class 
    void DoExecute() {}

    // Other private methods and members specialized for this class
}
```

In our end

```
void Main() {
     typedef std::shared_ptr<Base> BasePtr;
     std::vector<BasePtr> vec; 
     // Assume client derived classes creators are available. 
     vec.push_back(BasePtr(new ClientClass1())); 
     vec.push_back(BasePtr(new ClientClass2())); 
     for (auto& step : vec) {
          step->Start();
     }         
}
```

BTW, this is very simplied verison. Please don't question why we have multiple specialized base classes instead of using the same base class and use pimpl, at this point, it is not possible.

Comment: Take a look at the `protected` access specifier. That might solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, protected are no going to solve it :(  I don't want to send the base.h and SpecializedBase1.h and SpecializedBase2.h with all private members in the files to clients.

Comment: Well, the DoExecute members supposed to be overridden must be protected, rather than private. You might want to use '=0' declaration wherever abstract base classes are not supposed to provide their own implementation, and the 'override' keyword in all derived classes to safeguard these against typos. I assume your question is rather about Base::Execute and other private members, which deliberately not meant to be overridden?

Comment: Why do you want to hide them, and what do you mean by “hide”?

Comment: @MichaelSteffens The virtual private DoExecute() works fine, actually it is preferred that the virtual function to be private. I don't make DoExecute() to be pure virtual because I want the Base class itself to be complete and can be defined by itself.

Comment: @PeteBecker Because first there are many private members and methods that I don't want to expose to the client. Second, I may change the private implementation but keep the interface unchanged, I don't want to bother clients every time I make some change.

Comment: Neither of those is a problem. Code that derives from your intermediate classes can’t access private members, so won’t mysteriously fail if you change the private members. It will have to be recompiled, but that’s routine.

Comment: @PeteBecker The thing is that I don't want the client to even see the private members and methods. Only the public interface can be seen by clients.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ pimple idiom".

Comment: @Charlie if the client is expected to be able to execute the code your efforts will be thwarted in any number of ways. If the client is expected to be able to *debug* the code, your efforts will be *trivially* thwarted. Learn to trust the people you work with, or don't work with them.

Comment: Try this: inherit the Base class by the Specialized class using the private inheritance. Ex: class SpecializedClass : private BaseClass

Comment: @EOF It is not about trust. We trust the clients, but we don't want to expose all the private details to the clients when we sell the software to the clients.

Comment: @Charlie: You are right, missed that. As the overridden function DoExecute is nowhere accessed outside the base class, other than being overridden, private virtual does fine. With respect to data members my guess is: no luck other than using PIMPL idiom. Reason below.

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution: If

- you only need hidden private functions (no member variables)
- and it is acceptable to make all visible members these functions need to access public

then you could provide these hidden "members" outside the class as non-members, with an explicit pointer to the object. These function can be implemented in the corresponding *.cpp files without being mentioned in the declaration, using static internal linkage or in anonymous namespace, and become completely invisible to clients.

The idea breaks, as soon as you also have private data to hide. The reason is object allocation on the stack. In that case it is the client's responsibility to provide the required memory, which therefore needs to know the object's memory layout including all private members. Impossible, if you hide them. To accomplish this, your would need heap allocation in the constructor, which boils down to PIMPL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have private members to hide. I have been thinking about using PIMPL, however, this breaks the clients derived class derive from the single common Base class.